# duplicated resource id with search_plate under android.support.v7.appcompat.R.java

Tags: android

when build my App I got this error:

```
01-31 13:28:58.594 E/AndroidRuntime(10369): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-31 13:28:58.594 E/AndroidRuntime(10369): Process: com.example.app, PID: 10369
01-31 13:28:58.594 E/AndroidRuntime(10369): java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: No static field framelayout_content of type I in class Lcom/sdk/sample/R$id; or its superclasses (declaration of 'com.sdk.sample.R$id' appears in /data/app/com.example.app
```

when I search for the resourceId of "framelayout_content"

in the android.support.v7.appcompat.R.java file:

```
public static final int search_plate = 0x7f0f0057;
```

and in my R file of a module(com.sdk.sample.R.java):

```
public static int framelayout_content=0x7f0f0057;
```

the ids are duplicated!
and in the final R file(com.example.app.R.java) it only have:

```
public static final int search_plate=0x7f0f0057;
```

`framelayout_content` was gone, which lead to the error!

anyone could help on this?

PS:
I tried to rename the `framelayout_content` it didn't help.

the following is my project structure:

in settings.gradle:

```
include ':app', ':Module'
```

under app:

```
dependencies {
    compile project(': Module')
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    testCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'

}
```

under Module:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.squareup:otto:1.3.8'
}
```

Comment: Clean-Rebuild Please.

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya I have tried many times :(

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya thanks! solved I have two layout files with same name!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 01-31 13:28:58.594 E/AndroidRuntime(10369):
>   java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: No static field

[**`NoSuchFieldError`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NoSuchFieldError.html) can only occur at run time if the definition of a class has incompatibly changed.So findout **`DUPLICATE`** **XMLS** in project. Just Rename one of them. Then **`Clean-Rebuild and Run`**.

**FYI**

```
public static final int search_plate = 0x7f0f0057;
```

> Android R.java is an auto-generated file by aapt (Android Asset
>   Packaging Tool) that contains resource IDs for all the resources of
>   res/ directory.

Answer (score 2):

Solved by rename one of layout file, it's because the layout file which contain `framelayout_content` have the same name with the one in module. thanks for @IntelliJ Amiya